# How to convert time format in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Time I have in the following format`<?= $post['created_at'] ?>` Output: 2018-08-03 11:44:59

How can coordination work like the following example : ago 2 month !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it 's less a matter of code igniter, butt rather a date time php thing. You can get it with the DateTime class of php.

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$then = new \DateTime('2018-08-03 11:44:59');

$difference = $nof->diff($then, true);
```

Now you hace the difference between now and then in a DateInterval object. With this you can easily display the difference in the format you want.

```
echo $difference->days . ' ago'; // n days ago
```

If you want to get exactly the number of weeks which run by, you have to do some math.

```
echo floor($now->diff($then, true)->days / 7);
```

Same works for every format you want.
That 's it.